# Is there a way to declare protocol property as private?

Tags: swift, protocols, access-control

I want to conform to a protocol, as well as to hide its conformed properties to be accessed (declare them as `private`).

Consider the following:

```
protocol P {
    var value: String { get }

    init(value: String)
}

class C: P {
    var value: String

    required init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I would create a `C` object:

```
let myObject = C(value: "Hello World")
myObject.value = "New Value"
```

Based on that I have 2 questions:

Now, if I tried to declare `value` as private:

```
private var value: String { get }
```

the compiler will throw an error:

> 'private' modifier cannot be used in protocols

with a fix suggestion to replace the `private` with `internal`.

How can I prevent `value` from being accessible by saying `myObject.value`? if there is no way, what's the reason of this limitation?

Comment: The whole point of a protocol is to define (some of) the capabilities of a class implementing it to the outside world. It’s not a blueprint for how to design and implement a class. So private makes very little sense in a protocol.

Comment: You cannot set a value to a variable declared in protocol with only { get }. This is working as expected for me. The error thrown is "Cannot assign to property: 'variable' is a get-only property"

Comment: Your second question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50436344/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for that. I tried with a bool variable and it worked as expected, so i assumed it would work for string as well. My bad.

Comment: Also the point we were missing has been answered neatly as a comment in the same thread by @rmaddy "FYI - your struct does not "inherit" the protocol. It "conforms to" the protocol."

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You cannot make it invisible as a property of `myObject` if it needs to be publicly visible as a property of `(myObject as P)`

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for the link. Question 2 has been removed :)

Comment: If this property needs to be private then it should not be in protocol. Protocol is  an interface which defines a public behavior that can be adopted by many instead of one. `Private` limits the access to a specific type which is against the whole purpose of interfaces.

Comment: @MartinR In fact I preferred to ask about the general issue instead of dive deep into the details. I am trying to apply the *Chain of Responsibility* using protocol, based on what I did [here](https://gist.github.com/AhmadFayyas/36bb37031a529c79980e8a8b5211bba3), I want to prevent the ability of doing `fresh.higherLevel = ...`, I want to set `higherLevel` only from the initilizer, that's the whole point. Thanks for you kind consideration in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conforming to

```
protocol P {
    var value: String { get }

    init(value: String)
}
```

requires a gettable property `value` with default access. If write access to the 
property in the conforming class should be restricted to the class itself
then you can declare it as in [Swift readonly external, readwrite internal property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708439/swift-readonly-external-readwrite-internal-property):

```
class C: P {
    private(set) var value: String

    required init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let myObject = C(value: "Hello World")
print(myObject.value) // OK
myObject.value = "New Value" // Error: Cannot assign to property: 'value' setter is inaccessible
```

And if the property should only be set in initializers then make it
a *constant:*

```
class C: P {
    let value: String

    required init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let myObject = C(value: "Hello World")
print(myObject.value) // OK
myObject.value = "New Value" // Error: Cannot assign to property: 'value' is a 'let' constant
```

Comment: It seems to be sensible to declare it as `private(set)`, so there is no way to declare it as `private`, right?

Comment: @AhmadF: `private` would imply `private(get)` and that cannot fulfill the protocol requirement. (It that were possible then you could make any private property visible by adding a protocol conformance, and bypass the access control.) – You can make *both* protocol and the property fileprivate or internal, if that helps.

Comment: @AhmadF: Reading your comment *"I want to set higherLevel only from the initilizer"* again: In that case you can declare the property simply as a constant.